Travelling to Russia with a visitor visa without staying at the hotel mentioned on the voucher?
I am planning to travel to the Russian Federation from mid-May to mid-June from Canada. I am applying for a tourist visa that is valid for 30 days. I got my voucher that is required for issuing the visa through an accredited travel agency. On that voucher, there is the name of a hotel in which I guess I am supposed to stay. My question is if I am not planning to stay in that hotel, but rather in my friend's apartment in Moscow, is there going to be any trouble with the border authorities there? Does anyone know if they ask for the hotel receipts or anything of that kind during the entry process or when exiting the country? Do you get stopped on the streets for random checks as a tourist? Is the tourist visa and the voucher from the travel agency enough for the authorities there?

Does this answer your question? Russia - staying at friend's place with tourist visa See also https://www.visahouse.com/en/information/visaregistration/

Many governments are warning against all travel to Russia eg Canada IMHO attempting to stay in a friend’s apartment without the correct authorisation is a huge risk.

https://ru.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/russian-visas/ has a lot of useful info. See the "Visa Registration" part especially. You might make it out OK, but it's a risk. Not sure if you need to have this registration certificate for a random police check on the street, but you are supposed to have your passport and migration card at all times (originals, not copies).
